# ElasticSearch Painless Scripts - Field Context does not allow Text Fields - What context adds just Text Fields?

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

I am evaluating whether I can safely use painless scripting for one of our applications. We only feel comfortable with very strict contexts. The "Field" context seems the safest because it only allows read-only against the document. However, I would like to be able to include queries against text fields but "doc values are not available as text fields by default". Does anyone know how to loosen this context slightly to allow text fields?

Thanks

Comment: It would be helpful if you can provide more context on what you're trying to achieve. Are you sure that scripting is the only way?

Comment: yes. assume scripting is a requirement. I thought I was being pretty clear I am asking for a very specific lessening of constraint against painless "Field" context. thanks!

Comment: There's a bit of a contradiction here... how can scripting be a "requirement" since you're "evaluating whether painless scripting can be safely used"? Just curious

Answer (score 1):

You can access `text` fields in scripts (within "Field" context) by going through `params['_source']` instead of doc values which are not available for `text` fields.

For example, to compute the length of a `text` field you can use the following script:

```
params._source['my-text-field'].length()
```

i.e. `params._source['my-text-field']` is actually the raw string that is present in your source document.